# Keeping the Sandbox Clean - Delete Unchanged Posts

Tags: discussion, sandbox

In consideration with other conversations regarding the sandbox I had a thought as there have been complaints of the sand box being crapped up with posts that users apparently have no plans to update.

Can we set a two week time frame for posts to be edited and finalized for main before users/mods vote to (or straight up) delete them?

Two weeks should be more than enough time to post a question and get it edited.  Anything that sits longer likely is not going to be changed.

If we choose to do this we would want to update the main sandbox post to inform users of the rule.

Comment: I'd raise the limit to say that after two weeks the OP should be pinged with a comment and after 4 weeks total with 2 weeks without any activity the question should be deleted. But in general a good idea and I support this kind of addition to the Sandbox Rules.

Comment: I just found a question from you from some time ago where you basically asked the same: [Sandbox cleanup](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/sandbox-cleanup)

Comment: @Secespitus Ironically, they both have seven upvotes (as of now).

Comment: @Secespitus ...ok that's funny.  I don't remember writing that at all.