# Catalog of common comment scripts

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

Over the course of time I have copied the common comment statements of others (e.g. "Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!") and have had my comment statements copied by others.

The problem is that simply copy-and-pasting the statement means losing all the code, such as the [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links) and [more here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/157730) (of which there are many and I don't use them as often as I should).

To help out new users, please post your favorite or common comment scripts below.  **Please remember that magic links only resolve in comments, they do not resolve in posts.**  For the convenience of all, it means a bit of work for we posters.  I recommend the following format.

***New users: you would copy-and-paste the "code" in the PRE block, not the text in the example block.***

---

> This is what my script will look like after it's rendered.  This means Magic Links like **help center** and **tour** are rendered for users.

```
<pre>This is what my script will look like after it's rendered.
This means Magic Links like [help] and [tour] are rendered
for users.</pre>
```

Comment: Magic links also work for `[edit]` ([edit]) and `[chat]`([chat]). There's some more [listed here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5254/are-there-any-rules-or-a-specific-format-for-welcome-to-worldbuilding-comment/5255#5255).

Comment: @FoxElemental, you know, my kingdom for a complete list of the magic links... insofar as I've found, there isn't one.

Comment: @JBH There's at least https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/157730

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelKjörling, I didn't even notice that the page I linked was marked duplicate to what you listed.

Comment: So, @HDE22686 brought up the magical [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) extension [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46276701#46276701) a few days ago and I just found it but it's definitely worth a look if you find yourself using a lot of these or have a random text file stored somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I'm storing this one here for the Sandbox people (okay, basically just me) and is adopted from Secespitus' common script.

> This is a reminder about [keeping the Sandbox clean](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/sandbox-cleanup#4912): are you still working on this draft? If so, please [edit] it to show how we may further help you. If not, please **edit** your draft to shorten it to something like "Not posted: *title*" and delete it. The current guidelines are that a draft is eligible for deletion after 30 days without an **edit** from the OP and a comment like this one for at least 7 days.

```
This is a reminder about [keeping the Sandbox clean](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/sandbox-cleanup#4912): are you still working on this draft? If so, please [edit] it to show how we may further help you. If not, please [edit] your draft to shorten it to something like "Not posted: *title*" and delete it. The current guidelines are that a draft is eligible for deletion after 30 days without an [edit] from the OP and a comment like this one for at least 7 days.
```

Answer (score 2):

Mine is this one:

> Welcome to Worldbuilding, (Insert username)! If you have a moment, please take the **tour** and visit the **help center** to learn more about the site. You may also find **Meta** and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

The tour, help center, and Meta would all convert from magic links. The raw script (what you should copy+paste) is

`Welcome to Worldbuilding, (Insert username)! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!`

I'll modify as needed by changing parts of it or adding another notice. Remember to update it with the new link in case there's a new Sandbox (the current one is [this one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)).

I adapted it from this answer from [Are there any rules or a specific format for "Welcome to WorldBuilding!" comments?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5254/are-there-any-rules-or-a-specific-format-for-welcome-to-worldbuilding-comment/5255#5255) But felt that meta and The Sandbox should be mentioned, and later on the post on "Welcome to Worldbuilding!". Sometimes I'll customize it with magic links like `[edit]` or `[chat]`, or things like "Nice first question!" If I mean it. I pop into the first Q/A review queue, add this message to each new post, and then hit the skip button — it lets me greet new users while letting others do the main review work, unless I feel like it that day.

**Don't forget** to change the "(insert username)" to the name of the user, or simply delete it. I've had it happen to me a couple times that I'll comment using this script but leave the "insert username" in and have to go back and fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Just threw this one at a new user! (Gently, of course!!)

Answer (score 2):

My Stuff.  A general welcome/ot/what is WB and then Be nice and on-topic.

```
Welcome bryan, to clarify some of the comments above:  Stack Exchange is a little different from your standard discussion forum.  The site is about specific questions with specific supported answers.  As it stands this is commentary and while potentially interesting is not an answer to the question.  Once you have gained rep via the site's mechanism you will be able to comment on posts.  In the meantime please check out the [tour] and [help] to get a better idea how the site functions.  Again welcome and happy world building.


[Be nice](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

[How to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
```

Oh and this is just for fun:

No:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46186521#46186521

Answer (score 1):

> You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions), which isn't a good fit for our site.  Please review this link and help us by improving your question.

```
You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions), which isn't a good fit for our site.  Please review this link and help us by improving your question.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our **tour**.  Thanks!

```
Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0):

> [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).

```
[SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).
```